# How to pass parameters thow callback functions

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a button with this code:

```
CardService.newTextButton().setText('Akte in Flox öffnen').setOnClickOpenLinkAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('testFunc').setParameters({test: "3"})).setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT);
```

the code of the callbackfunction:

```
function testFunc(e) {console.error(e);}
```

My problem:

How can I read the parameter "test"? In object "e" the property "parameters" is empty:

```js
{ parameters: {},
  userLocale: 'de',
  commonEventObject: 
   { timeZone: { id: 'Africa/Ceuta', offset: 3600000 },
     userLocale: 'de',
     platform: 'WEB',
     hostApp: 'GMAIL' },
  userCountry: '',
  userTimezone: { offSet: '3600000', id: 'Africa/Ceuta' },
  formInputs: {},
  formInput: {},
  clientPlatform: 'web',
  gmail: 
   { threadId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     accessToken: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     messageId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' },
  messageMetadata: 
   { accessToken: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     messageId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     threadId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' },
  hostApp: 'gmail' }
```

Comment: Have you tried `function testFunc(e) {console.error(e.parameters);}`? Also, sometimes Logger will give you more info than console log in Apps Script - `function testFunc(e) {Logger.log(e.parameters);}`

Comment: Thank you for your idea, Logger.log gives the same result:

{clientPlatform=web, hostApp=gmail, formInput={}, formInputs={}, parameters={}, userTimezone={offSet=3600000, id=Africa/Ceuta}, commonEventObject={userLocale=de, hostApp=GMAIL, timeZone={id=Africa/Ceuta, offset=3600000.0}, platform=WEB}, messageMetadata={messageId=XXXXXX, accessToken=XXX, threadId=XXX}, userLocale=de, userCountry=, gmail={threadId=XXXXXX, accessToken=XXXXXX, messageId=XXXXXX}}

Comment: Try calling the logger with `e.parameters` not just `e` please

Comment: `e.parameters` returns an empty object. I have tried this as well: `e.commonEventObject` it returns `{platform=WEB, hostApp=GMAIL, userLocale=de, timeZone={offset=3600000.0, id=Africa/Ceuta}}`

Comment: Can you provide your manifest file for the add-on and some more details about how to recreate your project? See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You are using the wrong method

Your code:

```js
CardService.newTextButton()
  .setText("Akte in Flox öffnen")
  .setOnClickOpenLinkAction( // ++++ THIS LINE +++++
    CardService.newAction()
      .setFunctionName("testFunc")
      .setParameters({ test: "3" })
  )
  .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT);
```

With modification:

```js
CardService.newTextButton()
  .setText("Akte in Flox öffnen")
  .setOnClickAction( // SHOULD BE THIS
    CardService.newAction()
      .setFunctionName("testFunc")
      .setParameters({ test: "3" })
  )
  .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT);
```

#### Reference

- [setOnClickAction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-button#setonclickactionaction)
- [setOnClickOpenLinkAction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-button#setonclickopenlinkactionaction)

Answer (score 0):

The method "setOnClickOpenLinkAction" works fine and was not the problem. Apparently apps script cannot handle chaining in this case. I have restructured the code and it works:

`var act = CardService.newAction(); act.setFunctionName('testFunc'); act.setParameters({test: "3"}); var btn = CardService.newTextButton().setText('AkteinFloxöffnen').setOnClickOpenLinkAction(act).setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT);`